# TensorFlow _pywrap_tensorflow_internal Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to get started with tensorflow and everytime I import it, I see this error. I usually import keras as well, but it crashes because of TensorFlow. When I import TensorFlow alone, I also see this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\0mega.patch\Python\Python\Tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

What is "*pywrap_tensorflow*", and why is it not present?
Is there anything I can do? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, `pywrap_tensorflow` requires `cuDNN`.
Please install `cuDNN` accordingly.

Before you install the `cuDNN` please check did you install the `CUDA` successfully. To check it, run `nvcc -V`.

Comment: I have an AMD Ryzen though